# How do we know that this decree was written by Cixi?

Tags: china, qing-dynasty

In another, extremely helpful [answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/55890/19711)  we found the handwritten text underlying many claims about Empress Dowager Cixi’s illiteracy (see aforementioned answer for example of such claim). But how do we know, this is actually written in **Cixi’s own hand?**
[image]

### TLDR

There are also very beautiful calligraphies attributed to Cixi, such as the following one (found [here](https://kknews.cc/zh-sg/culture/53xn586.html)) bearing a seal „慈禧皇太后御筆“. My goal is to find out whether one of the documents is falsely attributed. It is also conceivable that her writing was bad in 1865, but very good around 1903, when Katherine Carl and others described her as highly skilled with the large brush.[image]

Comment: I don't read Chinese, but that whole document looks like being in the same handwriting to me; so is this image of a copy of her decree?

Comment: Who claimed that she had? You haven't posted information on the provenance of this image.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven’t been able to find anything apart from “the internet widely accepts that Cixi wrote this by hand”. There are no signatures or seals or anything. I’m afraid that you might have to resort to characterising her handwriting by samples that were known to have been written by Cixi (there are handwriting samples with her seal on it), which might not be a History SE question.

Comment: OK, so the handwritten document is kept at [*The First Historical Archives of China*](http://www.lsdag.com/nets/lsdag/page/topic/Topic_1697_1.shtml?hv=) (中國第一歷史檔案館), with document number (檔號) `05-13-002-000790-0014`. If you want to find out more you'll have to take a personal trip there. [It looks like it's kept under a glass frame](https://i2.kknews.cc/SIG=2qq2ruv/n9s0002s41q057nqnon.jpg).

Comment: "the confusion of 行政 with 行正 seems to me a strong indication of very limited literacy."

This is not the case. Firstly, this mistake is similar to a normal typo or mispelling.
Secondly, it is common to substitute characters with the same radicals and pronunciations in written text.

Comment: I don’t want to be disrespectful. Plus I have no experience with edicts. But I have seen many many handwritten manuscripts. If I compare to the uglier ones among Dunhuang manuscripts, they do not nearly contain that many mistakes. However, that is not the issue here. I just want to collect the facts. Then let Chinese colleagues decide what they think of her proficiency …

Comment: @axsvl77 you will also not that in some cases the Hanzi used by Cixi is much harder to write than the one the linked article supposes to be correct. Example 嗣/似。So, unless the article is wrong, speed doesn’t seem to be the sole issue.

Comment: It might be worth asking in the Chinese language SE about the nature or severity of the supposed errors. It hardly seems unlikely that the question has already been studied.

Comment: @AaronBrick I edited the question, because everyone was distracted from the question.

Comment: Please edit all the comments into the question and then flag the comments for deletion.